# Comparing csv files with pySpark

Tags: python, csv, apache-spark, pyspark, export-to-csv

i'm brand new to pyspark, but i need to digg into it very fast.
I want to compare two (huge) csv files in pyspark and managed so far quite okay (I'm pretty sure, my code is way not fancy)
In the end i'd like to count the records which are matching and those which are not matching.

What i was able to achive is:

1. Loading csv into RDD's.

```
act="actual.csv"
exp="expected.csv"
raw_exp = sc.textFile(exp)                                                  
raw_act = sc.textFile(act)
```

2. i can count the amount of records by using .count()

```
print "Expected: ", raw_exp.count()
print "Actual:", raw_act.count()
```

3. I can compare the rdds by using subtract and collect to get the records which dont match:

```
notCompRecords  = raw_exp.subtract(raw_act).collect()
```

Now i want to count those records which don't match.
I thought i would use:

```
notCompRecords.count()
```

but i got the error that an Argument is missing:

```
TypeError: count() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)
```

I also learned that i have to convert an List which notComRecords obvously is into a string by:

```
notCompString   = ''.join(notCompRecords)
```

but this also doesn't work.

How can i count the lines in the Object/Variable/rdd notCompRecords?

Thanks!
Any hint or clue is appreciated.
Best Regards,

Comment: Remove the `.collect()` from `notCompRecords = raw_exp.subtract(raw_act).collect()`. After that you can use `notCompRecords.count()`.

Comment: Wow! That went well, very quick! Thank you very much!

Comment: Thanks for giving the fast assurance this worked, sometimes people do not come back, when their problem is being solved. Now we might upvote @jho's comment, as it **really added something** to the question - an answer ;-)

Comment: Just added it as answer.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the .collect() from notCompRecords = raw_exp.subtract(raw_act).collect(). After that you can use notCompRecords.count().